# MSVC Error C3015 (bad OpenMP for loop) but not an obvious mistake

Tags: c++, visual-c++, openmp

I'm compiling some C++ code in Visual Studio 2022.  I'm using `/std:c++17 /O2 /permissive- /openmp:llvm /MP /arch:AVX2` as compiler settings.  I'm getting the compiler error

```
C3015   initialization in OpenMP 'for' statement has improper form
```

However, I'm feeling like this might be a compiler bug (possibly with `/openmp:llvm`), since I can't even make the simplest OpenMP for loop work in this context.  The for loop lives inside a lambda that's defined inside a template function that lives in a namespace (outside any class or struct) in a header file.  Something like:

```cpp
namespace Foo {
template <typename Func>
void f(Func work, const int beta, bool check = false) {
  auto mylambda = [](std::vector<double>& y, double a) {
      #pragma omp parallel for
      for (int test = 0; test < 0; test++)
          printf("Hello C3015\n");
  };

  work();
}
}
```

I have seen C3015 in the past when trying to use long (signed/unsigned) loop variables, but this is not that.  Also, the exact code compiles fine under `gcc`, so this is something specific about MSVC behavior.  There are other OpenMP for loops in this header file (in other functions etc.) that do not throw this error.

I'm just wondering whether there is some usage mistake I'm making, or if there is some workaround.  Or if this is an unavoidable compiler bug, at least how to report such a thing and maybe get it fixed.

Comment: The condition in your `for` loop : `test < 0` will never be true.

Comment: This does not affect whether the C3015 is generated or not; I can replace that 0 with a positive constant or a variable and obtain the same error.

Comment: For what (little) it's worth, a quick check on Godbolt indicates that this is new with the latest version of the compiler: https://godbolt.org/z/Wxz489Yez, and works fine on older versions: https://godbolt.org/z/h7jGfTna6.

Comment: Excellent to know this was not a bad question then, an upvote is appreciated :) Thank you for providing the minimal examples and identifying this as a compiler bug and regression!  Sadly this means there is probably no fix except switching to a slightly older compiler version and/or waiting for a bug fix...

Comment: @davewy I actually meant it as a side note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comment by @Jerry Coffin, this is a compiler bug that is a regression between x64 msvc 19.31 and 19.32.  It turns out this bug has already been [reported](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cannot-use-OpenMP-in-a-lambda-in-a-templ/10075732) to Microsoft and a fix is pending release (I would guess in the next minor MSVC update).